# What would cause lockfileVersion in package-lock.json to decrease by one?

Tags: node.js, npm, package-lock.json

Bumped the patch version in a package.json (manually, edited file). Noted that the lock file had the old version, so I did an `npm install` to update it. When I did that the `lockfileVersion` field went from `2` to `1`. This seems odd. The [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#lockfileversion) about `lockfileVersion`:

> An integer version, starting at 1 with the version number of this
> document whose semantics were used when generating this
> package-lock.json.

Well that didn't help. So is this change in values of the version a concern? It seems like an odd change, for it to decrease like that. Should I not update the lockfile when I bump the version?

Node v12.16.1, NPM 6.14.10

Comment: *"Bumped the patch version"* - how? `npm version patch` *does* update the lockfile too, doesn't it?

Comment: ah, no I did it manually be editing, I was in the package.json file for something else and just bumped that version while I was there; I'll try with `patch` and see what happens

Comment: interesting: I used `npm version patch` and the `lockfileVersion` stayed at 2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#lockfileversion

lockfileversion 2 is NPM 7. So one person on my team was using NPM 7 while I was still on 6 (lockfileversion 1).

Comment: did this cause any issues between your team? We just built a new machine and did npm i after cloning the repo and we noticed the lock file changed to version 2 and looked completely different. We pushed that update to the repo. It says it's backwards compatible, so I guess it shouldn't be an issue for devs with older versions, but I'm just wondering if the behavior is different in terms of resolving from the lock file and not package.json

Comment: Nah I think I'm the only person that even noticed it. But I recommend restricting your node version and getting an agreement about it.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably just because you used an older `npm` version than the one that was used the last time the `package-lock.json` file was changed. Update your `npm` executable and it should use a greater or equal `lockfileVersion` now.

Comment: Yeah it appears that `npm` was at 7.0 at that time but 6.x was still being updated. One person on my team must have been on 7 and I was on 6.